# Converting a hh:mm float to format using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

i want to convert a time to number like( 16:40 to 16.4)

15:40 to 15,4 using python

```
query = "SELECT date,time,windspeed,rainfall,winddirrection,temperature FROM *****"
        cur.execute(query)
        data_kampi = cur.fetchall()
        data1=np.array([data_kampi], dtype='object')
        N1=data1.shape
        x=np.squeeze(data1)

        #convert numpy to pandas
        xpandas=pd.DataFrame(x, columns=["Date", "Time", "Windspeed", "Rainfall", "Winddirection", "Temperature"])

        #print(xpandas.head())
        xpandas.to_csv("test.csv", header=True, index=False)
        xnumpy=np.array(xpandas)
```

Comment: Can you be more clear? Do you need a "hh:mm" to float conversion and nothing else?

Comment: Why don't you convert it from the SQL statement?

Comment: Thank you all, i got it with answer 1. Yes i meant HH:MM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, you can use this:

```
xpandas['Time'] = xpandas['Time'].apply(lambda x: float(str(x).replace(':', '.')))
```

You may need to change the format before:

```
xpandas['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(xpandas['Time'], format='%H:%M').dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```